# SELECT count(column) slower than SELECT *

Tags: php, performance, sqlite, pdo, count

Two simple queries:

- `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_column = 1`

  Returns array with all the records, with columns and values. About 100K in total.    Takes ~40ms to complete.
- `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM some_table WHERE some_column = 1`

  Returns just the record count value, same count as the query above.  **Takes 1 second!!**

`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` tells me the same thing for both queries: that it's searching the table using index...

Am I missing something here? Why is getting the count slower than getting the actual records?

I really don't want to use the 1st query, because I just need the count, and fetching 100K records will surely use all available memory :(

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output:

query #1:

```
selectid    order   from    detail
0   0   0   SEARCH TABLE atts USING INDEX idxType (type=?)
```

query #2:

```
selectid    order   from    detail
0   0   0   SEARCH TABLE atts USING COVERING INDEX idxType (type=?)
```

Comment: Consider pasting the entire output of `EXPLAIN` into your question. Also, had you run the `SELECT *` before? The results might have been in the query cache. Are both timings consistently repeatable?

Comment: Yes. Even if they were fetched from the cache, why is the count not cached too?

Comment: Also, do you get the same results for `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: COUNT(*) is just as slow as count(id)

Comment: Why it was tagged with PDO?

Comment: I'm using the PDO class to read from the database. But I made these tests in some sqlite administration tool. The count query in my app that uses PDO is a little slower (around 4 seconds). That's why I opened the db in the admin tool and made these tests...

Comment: No doubt you are also using a PC and a mouse and a cup of coffee. But there is nothing relevant to PDO in the question.

Comment: So, ~40ms it takes to return an array from fetchAll()? or just a statement? BTW, does sqlite driver support rowCount()?

Comment: I didn't test SELECT * in my php script before, but now that I did it's just as slow as COUNT :| It seems it's fast only if I execute the query in the sqlite admin app (it's called "sqlite expert personal").

Comment: I suspected something like this. Then I would say that a toy-database is not fit for such data sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as it turned out, there is no difference between these two queries - thus, there is no question at all.

Speaking of the overall timing - apparently you have to move from a toy-database to a real one.

Comment: I think you're right and my admin app fetches results with some kind of LIMIT clause even though I did not add one in the query

Answer (score 2):

The whole problem has been due to caching. The first request it had to fetch data from server and second request there was no need to.

Re run both codes interchanging both queries or running it multiple times and you will know that there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that it would be a case of it having to keep memory of the ids that have already been accounted for and also needs to check for NULL entries.

If you haven't already, I'd suggest adding an index on your `some_column` to speed that up too.